# Django rest framework router not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

In my application I'm using `ModelViewSet`, as for urls I used `SimpleRouter()`:

main.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^teams/', include('team.urls', namespace='teams')),
]
```

team.urls

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('', views.TeamViewSet, base_name='teams')
router.register('players', views.PlayersViewSet, base_name='players')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

I want my urls to be like this: http://.../teams/ and http://.../teams/players/. 
My problem is when i leave `router.register('', views.TeamViewSet, base_name='teams')` empty it will get a not found 404 to players url, but if i add anything to the first url e.g: `router.register('anything', views.TeamViewSet, base_name='teams')`, it will work.

How can i make the urls the way i want and why isn't it working this way?

Comment: There will be a conflict between `/teams/{team_id}/` and `/teams/players/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the order of the url's

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('players', views.PlayersViewSet, base_name='players')
router.register('', views.TeamViewSet, base_name='teams')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and give you an answer

Comment: This worked for me but I didn't notice why! Anyone knows what happened on this case?